Rewiring USB Type B to MIDI
I am beginning work on building a MIDI VPO organ in my spare time. I have found some MIDI controllers online, I have not bought them yet, that I plan on gutting and repurposing for this project. However, the output they use is USB type B, and I would like for them to use MIDI for ease of finding cables and such. The keyboards are 3 Nektar SE61's, bought new. The shell will be removed, so that will not be an issue. How could I rewire the USB type B (female) output ports to MIDI female, or is that even possible?

Welcome! Do you have a spec sheet for the MIDI controllers? Are they outputting MIDI voltages and protocol on a (misused) USB type B connector, or are they outputting bona fide USB signals that carry MIDI information using USB signalling + some sort of USB protocol for MIDI?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

No it is not possible to just wire a USB connector to a MIDI connector. They are completely different electrical interfaces, buses and protocols.
Which is why you need an active piece of electronis with a chip that communicates USB with the computer on one end and communicates MIDI on the other end. You can buy these or some USB audio interfaces also contain a MIDI ports with built-in adapter.
Hoever it seems like you want to connect a USB device with MIDI device, instead of connecting MIDI device to USB host like a PC. A bit more trickier and some hobbyists may have built these from microcontrollers. It is simply easiest to have a USB host like a PC or Raspberry Pi, and connect the USB device there, and add an USB MIDI adapter, and route MIDI traffic between the two MIDI devices.
